# Time as stopping condition of infinite loop

Tags: python

```
# run infinitly
while(True):

  done = False;

  while(not done):
    #Do Stuff
    #Main Program

    #stopping condition of inner while loop
    if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 10:
      done = True
       if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 10:
          time.sleep(60-datetime.datetime.now().second)
```

I can't figure out why this will not work for me. The entire script is supposed to run on an infinite loop, and then the inner loop is supposed to go through until the stopping condition is met every 10 minutes.

It was my understanding, and maybe I am wrong, that using datetime.datetime.now().minute like I did in an if loop like that would set done = True every 10 minutes, and would end the loop and proceed with the rest of the script...until it realizes that its in another infinite loop and then its supposed to start all over.

Am I getting confused with how this command works, or is there something wrong with my code? Or is there even a better way to do it? The script will run, but it does not end the inner loop with that stopping condtion.

Comment: You probably shouldn't put a loop in a loop

Comment: @ChristianCareaga why not?

Comment: well then youre infintely looping the loop thats looping i dont know just sounds like there is an easier way

Comment: Unless I'm thinking about this incorrectly, `datetime.datetime.now().minute` is only going to equal 10 once every hour.

Comment: @JustinSBarrett I feared I might have confused it that way. Do you know of any way to make it every 10 minutes? This is only a test for what I want, I eventually want to make it restart once every 24 hours.

Comment: the datetime.datetime.now.minute()==10 will return true at 1:10. 2:10, 3:10, 4:10, etc(just an example) instead of 1:10, 1:20, 1:30, etc.

Comment: Make a new variable that is incremented by 10 every time the inner loop hits a 10-minute cycle, and compare `datetime.datetime.now().minute` to that variable.

Comment: modulo would be easier...

Comment: I would declare a `tic` variable before the loop (`tic = datetime.datetime.now()`) and inside the loop I would refresh some `toc` variable, like `toc = datetime.datetime.now() - tic`. Then, when `toc.minute > 10`, you break, sleep, or do what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to do it, but keeping close to your original design, I'd code the inner loop as:

```
while(not done):
    if datetime.datetime.now().minute % 10 == 0:
        done = True
    else:
        time.sleep(60-datetime.datetime.now().second)
```

(I'm assuming what you were trying to do with that second `if` was sleep until the next minute when you weren't ready to exit the loop.)

Comment: your code formatting's messed up. I can't edit/fix because it's too few changes >.<

Answer (score 1):

It stops every *tenth* minute: 1:10, 2:10, 3:10, etc. In order to do that, use something like:

```
import time

# in outer loop
inner_loop_start = time.time()

# in inner loop
    now = time.time()
    if now - inner_loop_start > 60*10:
        # done= True and all that jazz
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thrashing around constantly checking if it's 10 past the top of the hour, just do some math and sleep appropriately.  Time is generally deterministic.

```
import datetime
import time

def seconds_till_10past():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = now.replace(minute=10, second=0) - now
    return delta.seconds % 3600

while True:
    time.sleep(seconds_till_10past())
    print "Do something at 10 past the hour."
```

Also, don't parenthesize arguments to statements (e.g. `while(True)`), it's bad form.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer the question, but just in case all you want to achieve in the first place is to run some python code every (say) 10 minutes, you'd better implement this using [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron).

I assume you so far have a script that is somehow started at boot time. It mainly consists of an infinite loop, a main procedure, and a wait-until-next-execution-time component. For example like the following:

```
""" my_first_daemon.py
    does something everytime the datetime minute part is fully divisible by ten
"""

while True:
    # do something at 00,10,20,30,40,50 (minutes) every hour
    print "Hello World!"
    # wait until the next execution time
    wait_until_next_ten_minute_time()
```

If this is indeed the case I'd suggest to move the main section of your script to a separate script. For example like the following:

```
""" my_first_cronjob.py
    is run by cron everytime the datetime minute part is fully divisible by ten
"""

# do something at 00,10,20,30,40,50 (minutes) every hour
print "Hello World!"
```

The you go ahead and add to your crontab (use the command `crontab -e` to add the entry to that user's crontab that shall run the script, also have a look at the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)). For example like this:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *     command to be executed

# example entry:
# (divide minute-star by 10 to get it run every 10 minutes) 
*/10 *  *  *  *     python /path/to/my_first_cronjob.py
```

After the edit you should notice a message like *crontab: installing new crontab* and then you're done. Just wait and have a look if it works.

Some things to note as well:

- The script's output to stdout and stderr are sent to you by mail after termination. Have a look at `tail -f /var/mail/moooeeeep` (specify your username). You can also configure Thunderbird to fetch these mails, in order to inspect them easier.
- The corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a very good source of information for further details.
- If you need to keep state information between independent runs of the script, consider using a configuration file to store this state information, e.g., using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding from my comment above:

```
tic = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:

    # do stuff

    toc = datetime.datetime.now() - tic
    if toc.minute > 10:
        tic = datetime.datetime.now();
        time.sleep(60-datetime.datetime.now().second)
```

I have removed the "`done`" variable, since it conveys a meaning of finished. By reading your code, though, it seems you are actually pausing an ever ongoing process, actually.

Hope this helps!