# End a loop when current time is something specific

Tags: python

I have asked a question similar to this before, but this time it is a little different. To me, the following code should work.

```
import datetime
# run infinitly
while(True):

  done = False

  while(not done):
    #
    #main program
    #


    #stopping condition
      if currenttime == '103000':
        done = True

  #continue with rest of program
```

However, it doesn't continue with the rest of the program when it hits 10:30:00am.

The following program I KNOW works (on a raspberry pi):

```
import datetime
done = False
while not done:
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
    if currenttime != '103000':
        print currenttime
    if currenttime == '103000':
        done = True
print 'It is 10:30:00am, the program is done.'
```

It made logical sense to me what I did in that first example. Does anyone know why it won't exit that loop and continue with the rest?

Comment: Try to flush out the top code a bit. Where does `currenttime` come from, for example? What exactly happens at 10:30:00am?

Comment: Time as a stopping condition isn't a very good idea.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the rest of the program. And go learn about http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime why what you are doing is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

If the main program takes a long time to run, `currenttime` could jump from `102958` to `103005`. Therefore skipping `103000` entirely.

Comment: He could always have two times, `old_time` and `cur_time`. Then do `if old_time < 103000 and cur_time > 103000: done = True`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set currenttime, before you check?  Also, the `if` statement has to execute exactly at 103000 in order for `done = True` to execute.

```
while(True):

  done = False

  while(not done):
    #
    #main program
    #

    # need to set current time
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')

    #stopping condition (use >= instead of just ==)
      if currenttime >= '103000':
        done = True

  #continue with rest of program
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that is not guaranteed that your loop has one iteration in each and every available second. The more load is on your system, the larger the likelihood that the loops skips a second, which potentially would be the termination criterion. There are also cases where seconds may be skipped, e.g. due to time synchronization or daylight saving issues.

Instead of a busy waiting loop, you could pre-compute the timedelta in seconds and then sleep for that many seconds.

Advantages:

- You'll save computation power that other processes on your machine could use instead.
- It probably increases the lifetime of your hardware.
- This will also be more energy efficient.

Example:

```
import datetime
import time
def wait_until_datetime(target_datetime):
    td = target_datetime - datetime.datetime.now()
    seconds_to_sleep = td.total_seconds()
    if seconds_to_sleep > 0:
        time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)

target_datetime = datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 1)
wait_until_datetime(target_datetime)
print "Happy New Year 2025!"
```

Note that this may still fail to produce the desired behavior due to arbitrary changes of the systems date and time settings. Probably it would be best to adopt a completely different strategy to execute a specific command at a specific time. Have you considered implementing the desired behavior using a cron job? (You could send a signal to the process and thereby issue it to cancel the loop...)

Comment: Similar idea to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17353051/194586) to his other question.  Time passes at a fairly deterministic rate, no reason to constantly check as though it'll surprise you when the time you're waiting for rolls around.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
done = False
while True:
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
    if currenttime >= '103000':
        break
    print currenttime
print 'It is 10:30:00am, the program is done.'
```

If you can't use break:

```
import datetime
done = False
while not done:
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
    if currenttime >= '103000':
        done = True
    else:
        print currenttime
print 'It is 10:30:00am, the program is done.'
```